# Raster slope created in QGIS: values do not exist when imported into R

Tags: qgis, raster, r

I used an ocean bathymetry raster (depth) to create a slope raster in QGIS with the "declividad" raster tool. Besides the fact that I was only able to do this by converting the bathymetry raster to projected coordinates (does anyone know why and if I can change this?), when I import the slope raster to R, it appears that without values. But if I extract values for the points in QGIS it works fine.

Below I have attached a print of the raster information in QGIS:

[image]

When importing in R, it appears like this:

```
> slope <- raster::raster(here::here("declividade_global.tif"))     
> slope@data@values
logical(0)
>
```

Comment: Does the raster have anything? Does its summary or print show anything? For large rasters, the `raster` package doesn't load the data into memory until it really needs it, so maybe that's happening. Is `slope@data@inmemory` true or false?

Comment: ```slope@data@inmemory``` is false. I can't tell if he has anything, the information about him is like this: ```class: RasterLayer 
dimensions: 19249, 14583, 280708167  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution: 2746.38, 2746.38  (x, y)
extent: -15025383, 25025074, -16432216, 36432849  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs: +proj=merc +lat_ts=-2 +lon_0=-43 +x_0=5000000 +y_0=10000000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs 
source: declividade_global.tif 
names: declividade_global```

Comment: Did you try using `values()` or `getValues()` functions?

Answer (score 1):

The file has been understood correctly by `raster`, but its over the size threshold such that instead of reading in the data to R's memory at creation time, it only reads in the pixels it needs when it needs them. For example, if you wanted to sample the raster at a few locations, R only needs to read the data from disk for the pixels at those locations, saving memory (but taking a bit longer than if the data had been read into memory, if you have enough memory).

Here's an example using a large TIFF file I have:

```
> r
class      : RasterLayer 
band       : 1  (of  3  bands)
dimensions : 7491, 8331, 62407521  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 30, 30  (x, y)
extent     : 384885, 634815, 5928285, 6153015  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=utm +zone=30 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
source     : LE_image.tif 
names      : LE_image 
values     : 0, 255  (min, max)
```

I can't tell from that if its in memory or not, but there's an `inMemory` function:

```
> inMemory(r)
[1] FALSE
```

I can get the values with the `values` function, but note that this reads in the entire TIFF data, and then throws away all but the first five values (which are all zero here), so it may be slow or too much for your machine:

```
> values(r)[1:5]
[1] 0 0 0 0 0
```

R can do stuff with data on disk without reading it all in, for example `plot(r)` works because it will do a subset of the full raster and plot that because you probably can't see 7000x8000 pixels on your screen.

If you want to create an in-memory raster, you can do it with:

```
> r <- setValues(r, values(r))
```

and then:

```
> inMemory(r)
[1] TRUE
```

so the data object has values now:

```
> r@data@values[1:10]
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

but you should still use the `values` function because that works in both cases:

```
> values(r)[1:10]
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

See help for `?inMemory` for more examples.